# Is there any way to establish a communication between AS3 script and Apache Derby database directly?

Tags: java, json, actionscript-3, flash, servlets

I'm trying to build a flash app that communicates with derby database without any JS, XML or any intermediate stuff. I've read about SQLConnection (adobe reference ) instance but dont quietly get if it's able to do same with derby.

I am quiet familiar with JSON, JAVA EE but newbie to flash development. Help would be really appreciated.

If that's not possible I'd love to try JSON Post requests to servlet ( which whill ofcourse get the stuff from db ).

Comment: For AIR? Yes it's possible but not with SQLConnection, that stuff is for SQLite only. You'll have to create your own AS3 Apache Derby framework.

Answer (score 3):

No.  As BotMaster said, SQLConnection only works for a SQLLite local connection.  If you want to connect to any other DB technology, the standard procedure is to have what they call a Middle-Tier (Java,PHP,RoR,PHP) backend that manages the connection to your chosen DB tech.

To make this work, you would have to have a Java Web Container with the Derby stuff setup on that side.  Your AS3 application would then communicate with the Web Container through whatever format you desired (AMF, Json, Raw HTTP call).